# sending parameters in internal messages to smart optimistic rollup

Tags: smart-rollup

I have deployed the kernel from the 05_kernel_outbox example in the [kernel_gallery code repository](https://gitlab.com/tezos/kernel-gallery). However, I commented out the function call to ["write_outbox_message"](https://gitlab.com/tezos/kernel-gallery/-/blob/main/05_outbox_kernel/src/lib.rs?ref_type=heads#L34).

Now, I'm trying to send an internal message from a smart contract to the rollup. However, I can't manage that the a corresponding debug message is written to the kernel log.

In [my contract](https://better-call.dev/nairobinet/KT1P9q31fD9e4CJcg389WDmuJ8oLtWrVQnke/code) I pack the INT in order to get bytes, which seems not to work.

How do I have to make the call?

Many thanks:

Comment: Additional information: I used [tezos-smart-rollup-installer](https://docs.rs/crate/tezos-smart-rollup-installer/) to upgrade the kernel. 

Is this the problem, since the initial kernel deploys a rollup interface of type "CONTRACT BYTES" and not "CONTRACT INT"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `smart-rollup-installer` doesn't influence at all the type of the rollup.

When you originate the rollup, you need to select the type of the entrypoint.  so for an entrypoint of type `int`, you would do (modified from the [docs](https://tezos.gitlab.io/shell/smart_rollup_node.html#origination)):

```
octez-client originate smart rollup "${SOR_ALIAS}" \
  from "${OPERATOR_ADDR}" \
  of kind wasm_2_0_0 \
  of type int \
  with kernel "${KERNEL}" \
  --burn-cap 999
```

You would then be able to send an `INT` to the rollup from your smart contract - no need to pack the int.

If you were using the `smart-rollup-installer`, then `${KERNEL}` here would be `installer.hex`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that tezos-smart-rollup-installer has no deal with it.

The contract through which you submit the internal message to your rollup should send bare `int` as parameter, not `bytes`.